# QGIS 3.22.0 cannot toggle editing in Attribute table

Tags: attributes, qgis, editing

I want to select some features and edit their attribute but the toggle editing button wouldn't activate at all.

**Features** - from csv file with Latitude and Longitude values 
**Coordinate** - EPSG 4326 
**Map** - shapefile of South Korean peninsula

[image]

These are features on my map on QGIS 3.22.0

[image]

I selected one of the features.

[image]

When I open the selected feature’s table, the toggle editing button would not activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV files are not editable, save your layer to a geopackage and edit that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I saved as a Geopackage file from the existing cdv file, and it worked for me